# How can I use custom properties to set different background on different pages?

Tags: custom-field, pages

The problem isn't that complex (compared to the description I'll write :)) but I'd like to do this as correct as possible (e.g. I could be doing it wrong with Home.php), so I'll give you the whole context. 
As a part of my design, the page displays different background images. For that I use Supersized, "a fullscreen background slideshow built using the jQuery library". Some of my pages use one background image (no slideshow obviously :), and some use three. Also, I use javascript to detect the users monitor resolution and serve him an appropriate image size:

```
var imageToBeLoaded = "images/bg_index.jpg";
$(document).ready( function () {
if(window.screen.width > 1024) {
  imageToBeLoaded = "images/bg_index_large.jpg";
}});
```

So the problems are:

a) Home.php isn't a page accessible through WP-Admin so I can't give it custom fields.

Solution: `if  (isHome()){ setDefaultalues();}`

b) If I'm not on the homepage, I need to get the custom fields key/vaules but only for the properties that are related to the image background (and as I said before, ever page has 1 to N number of background images). For example, my About page has 5 properties, `bgImg1`, `smallImg1`, `bgImg2`, `smallImg2` and `greeting text`. That means I need to get all the variables and parse the name so I can get e.g. `bgImg1` and `bgImg2`. Additionally, Supersized needs a text description as another parameter, so the page needs to have two more parameteres, `desc1` and `desc2` which I also need to get and combine with the appropriate `bgImg` so I can generate output that looks like this (from the static page):

`{image : 'images/bg_rwanda.jpg', title : 'Rwanda Home'}, {image : 'images/bg_rwanda2.jpg', title : 'Rwanda School'}`

Pseudocode would look something like this:

```
var output = "{image : '";
var imageIsLarge= false;
if (getResolution() > 1024 ) { imageIsLarge= true; }
while (hasNextProperty()){
  Property prop = nextProperty();
  if (imageIsLarge) {
      if (prop.getKey().startsWith (bgImageL)){
         output += prop.getValue()+", title:";
         // etc. Also, I need to set the code to first get the first img, 
         // not just in any order and pair it with the first  description
```

Now this seems a bit complex and I have a feeling I could do it simpler, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 2):

You get custom field values with `get_post_meta()`.

Wordpress has a function called `wp_localize_script()` that's used to, as the name suggests, localized scripts by creating a javascript object from a PHP array.  When you use wp_enqueue_script() to add a script to the front end of wordpress, you can "localize" it by calling `wp_localize_script()` afterwards. If you need to get values from custom fields or some other place from the database into some sort of javascript object, this is probably the easiest way to do it.  Not exactly what `wp_localize_script` was designed for, but it will get the job done.

Here's an example:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpse23525_add_scripts' );
function wpse23525_add_scripts()
{

    // Only for single posts
    if( !is_single() ) return;

    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse23525_script', 'path/to/script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

    // We should have $post by now, but get it if not
    global $post;
    if( empty( $post ) ) $post = get_queried_object();

    $localize = array( 
        'some_key'      => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'some_key', true ),
        'another_key'   => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'another_key', true ),
        'one_more'      => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'one_more', true )
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'wpse23525_script', 'wpse23525_obj', $localize );
}
```

Which spits out this on the front end (values may change, of course):

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
/* <![CDATA[ */
var wpse23525_obj = {
    some_key: "test1",
    another_key: "test2",
    one_more: "test3"
};
/* ]]> */
</script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wp3.2path/to/script.js?ver=3.2.1'></script>
```

script.js would contain all the things you're planning on doing with the data, which can be accessed with `wpse23525_obj.some_key` or `wpse23525_obj.another_key` etc.

So this:

```
var imageToBeLoaded = "images/bg_index.jpg";
$(document).ready( function () {
if(window.screen.width > 1024) {
  imageToBeLoaded = "images/bg_index_large.jpg";
}});
```

becomes

```
var imageToBeLoaded = wpse23525_obj.another_key;
$(document).ready( function () {
if(window.screen.width > 1024) {
  imageToBeLoaded = wpse23525_obj.some_key;
}});
```

More reading:

1. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta
2. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script
3. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script
4. http://yoast.com/get-queried-object/

Comment: I'm sorry, you've put a lot of effort into the reply but I can't make heads or tails from your code. The variable names don't only confuse and I don't have an idea where would I put the first code block. The general idea is understandable though so thank you for taking your time and pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Ha, fair enough.  I didn't give you a working example, I figured you could take it from there.  The first bit of code would go in your functions.php file or a plugin file.